# Is there a way to get git to autocomplete commands based on a shortened version?

Tags: git, autocomplete, mercurial

When working for another company, I often used Mercurial for revision control. I actually like `git` better, but one thing that really annoys me is that in Mercurial, if I type:

```
hg stat
```

It is smart enough to realize that the only command that could have been in place of this is `hg status`, thus executing the command for me.

I know that `git` doesn't do this by default, but I would like it to. (BTW, I've read http://www.evanjones.ca/git-shortcuts.html and know about aliases, but I'd like to not have to setup an alias every time I want this behavior.)

I could probably write an addon for `git` that does this, but I'm wondering first if there's a way to configure `git` to recognize this is the behavior I want, and if not, is there already a plugin for this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to that? I'm at exactly the same point.

Comment: Not really. I am thinking about writing a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Git Bash does autocomplete commands when you hit TAB. If there is more than one option for the prefix you type, hitting TAB twice will display all the options. It even auto completes branch names.

`git stat` will be completed to `git status` when you click TAB.

Comment: Hmm, so that's not exactly what I'm looking for, though. I was thinking more along the lines if I type `git stat` and hit Return, then git will automatically know that I want git status.

Comment: Also, I should mention that I'm looking for a platform-independent way of doing this - git bash seems to only be available on windows... (My terminal on Mac OS/X doesn't autocomplete like you mention).

Comment: @jwir3 I didn't know this was only available on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You said you'd rather not set up aliases, but there are plenty of pre-made lists that you can copy/paste into your config. [This](https://gist.github.com/igal/53855) is one such example.

Comment: The reason I didn't want to setup aliases is that sometimes I type `git st`, sometimes `git stat`, sometimes `git sta`, etc... It's just a pain to setup all these aliases, although I could do it. I'm just wondering if there's a more all-encompassing solution, such as what `hg` provides.